# C++11: What's the difference between "parameter pack" and "variadic template"?

Tags: templates, c++11, parameters, pack, variadic

Seen from the introduction http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack, seems the concept of "parameter pack" is something the same as "variadic template". So what's the conceptual difference between them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Syntactically, parameter pack is a part of a variadic template. For example,

```
template<class ... Types> struct Tuple {};
```

is a variadic structure template, and `Types` is a parameter pack in it. `Tuple` itself is not a parameter pack.

You may pass any set of type parameters to `Tuple`, and they will be packed to `Types` pack. For example in the code

```
Tuple<int, float, std::string> foo;
```

we instantiated a `Tuple` template with `int`, `float` and `string` types and got a structure of actual type `Tuple<int, float, std::string>`. The code of `Tuple` may now [expand](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack#Pack_expansion) `Types` pack.